# Is combining Null-conditional operations with Null-coalescing operations redundant?

Tags: c#

Im a bit confused about an example found on the C# official documentation, where it says that combining the null-conditional operator with the null-coalescing operator can be used to assign default values.

This is the example used on MSDN:

`first = person?.FirstName ?? "Unspecified";`

But that to me looks like its the same as:

`first = person.FirstName ?? "Unspecified";`

I even tested them and both behave the same, so I wonder if I'm missing something or its just redundant to used the former?

Comment: They are not the same if `person` is null.

Comment: In your second code - If `person` was null, then you'd get a null reference error, regardless.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are not the same if `person` is null. If `person` is null the second line would throw a `NullReferenceException`. THat's the whole point of the `?.` operator.